# Bloquear Botón si campos están en blanco

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

quiero que el botón que utilizo para guardar los datos este loqueado si los campos del formulario se encuentran en blanco.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

   if(document.getElementById("id_tip").value = 0 ){

          $("#Ingresar").prop("disabled", true);
     }

});
```

Traté de hacerlo de esta forma, sin embargo no funciona. Este campo es de tipo Select, cuya option seleccionada al cargar la vista, en el value, es igual a 0. No conozco mucho de validaciones, por lo que cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida. Necesito que se valide de esta forma, ya que uno de los docentes que me evaluará no considera correcto que las validaciones se realicen una vez presionado el botón para ingresar los datos, si no más bien que estas deben de realizarse antes. De antemano gracias.

```
 <div class="box-body">

    <div class="row">

     <form id="subida" name="subida">

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Perfil</label>
      <?= form_open(base_url().'C_Horarios/hacerAlgo'); ?>
       <select class="form-control" id="id_tip" name="id_tip">
         <option value="0">--Seleccione un Perfil--</option>
         <?php 
                foreach ($tipo as $i) {
                    echo '<option value="'. $i->id_tip .'">'. $i->descripcion_tip .'</option>';
                }
            ?>

       </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Usuario</label>
       <select class="form-control" id="rut_usu" name="rut_usu">
         <option value="0">--Seleccione un Usuario--</option>
       </select>
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label>Seleccione un xlxs</label>
         <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".xlsx" class="form-control" > 
       </div>
      </div>

     <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Fecha Ini.</label>
         <input type="date" name="fecha_ini" id="fecha_ini" class="form-control" > 
      </div>
     </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Fecha Ter.</label>
         <input type="date" name="fecha_ter" id="fecha_ter" class="form-control" > 
      </div>
     </div>




     <div class="col-md-3" style="top:25px; left: 10px;" >
                <div class="form-group">

                    <button type="submit" id="Ingresar" name="Ingresar" class="btn bg-aqua">Guardar</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            </div>


  </div>
```

Comment: Se requiere que especifiques. ¿Todos los campos del formulario o un campo en específico o un rango de campos?

Comment: Todos los campos del formulario, que no queden en blanco. En el formulario tengo campos de tipo Select, File y Date

Comment: Pues creo que la mejor solución en tu caso será implementar algún plugin de validación de jQuery, por [ejemplo este](https://jqueryvalidation.org) o cualquier otro, hay varios que funcionan muy bien, a no ser que quieras intentar reinventar la rueda.

Comment: Pero hace lo que requiero? es decir bloquea el botón si  los campos están en blanco? no me sirve si lo hace después, ese es el problema :C, actualmente también uso Jquery, no se si es otra librería a la que te refieres.

Comment: Actualicé el link con un validador más actualizado es una librería que usa jQuery. Funcionan muy bien, no sé si desactivan el botón, tendrás que revisar la documentación, aunque eso puede ser intrascendente ya que el validador no envía nada si faltan datos por llenar, luego hay varias formas de indicar que faltan datos, sea mediante mensajes al salir de los campos u otras formas. Si usas Bootstrap, creo que también vienen con opciones de validación.

Comment: Uso Bootstrap, sin embargo no se como hacer lo que requiero por eso pregunto, gracias por responder de todas formas.

Comment: [Aquí tienes algunos ejemplos](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation)  para validar campos usando el mismo Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunca había hecho una validación como la que pides, pues siempre validaba después de darle click al botón, acá te dejo un código de lo que se me ocurrió para resolver tu caso, espero que te sirva cualquier inquietud no dudes e preguntar.

```js
var elementosVacios = Array();

    $('input, select, textarea').not('input[type=button], input[type=reset], input[type=submit], input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]').each(function(){
    
        elementosVacios.push($(this).attr('name'))

        $(this).focusout(function(){
            var valor = $(this).val();

            var posicion = elementosVacios.indexOf($(this).attr('name'));

            if (valor == '' || valor == 0) {
                if (posicion == -1) {
                    elementosVacios.push($(this).attr('name'));
                }
            }else{
                if (posicion > -1) {
                   elementosVacios.splice(posicion, 1);
                }
            }

            if (elementosVacios.length == 0) {
                $("#Ingresar").removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        })
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-body">
    <form id="subida" name="subida">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Perfil</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="id_tip" name="id_tip">
                        <option value="0">--Seleccione un Perfil--</option>
                        <option value="Ejemplo">Ejemplo</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Usuario</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="rut_usu" name="rut_usu">
                        <option value="0">--Seleccione un Usuario--</option>
                        <option value="Ejemplo">Ejemplo</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Seleccione un xlxs</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".xlsx" class="form-control" > 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Fecha Ini.</label>
                    <input type="date" name="fecha_ini" id="fecha_ini" class="form-control" > 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Fecha Ter.</label>
                    <input type="date" name="fecha_ter" id="fecha_ter" class="form-control" > 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3" style="top:25px; left: 10px;" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" id="Ingresar" name="Ingresar" class="btn bg-aqua" disabled="disabled">Guardar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Tu ejemplo funciona genial si lo ejecuto desde stackoverflow, sin embargo no funciona si lo hago desde mi servidor local, lo cual me parece extraño hahaha, gracias por responder

Comment: Extraño, revisa bien el código probablemente se te fue alguna llave sin cerrar o algún carácter donde no debía ir

Answer (score 2):

Una forma de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
function control(){
  if (document.getElementById("file").value!=="" &&
    document.getElementById("fecha_ini").value!=="" &&
    document.getElementById("fecha_ter").value!=="") {

        document.getElementById("Ingresar").disabled=false; 

  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("Ingresar").disabled=true; 
    alert('Ingrese los campos requeridos');
  }
```